# For every finite set $V$ in $K^n$, find a linear polynomial such that the associated function is injective in $V$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to prove that for each finite subset $V$ of $K^n$, with $K$ an algebraically closed field, there exists a polynomial of degree 1 such that the associated function $L: V \rightarrow K$ is injective. I tried to explicitly determine $L$, failing, and also induction on $card\left ( V \right )$, without any success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a hint do not read below this line: Consider a family of linear functions, and prove at least one of them should be injective. This is a common theme when you are trying to prove something exists while you suspect "almost everything" would do the trick.

For a complete solution:

Let $p_1,\ldots, p_r\in K^n$. For an $n$-tuple $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ define $L_a(p)=\sum a_ip_i$. Consider the map $$f:K^n\rightarrow K$$ that maps $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ to 
$$f(a)=\prod_{i\neq j} \left(L_a(p_i)-L_a(p_j)\right).$$

This is a polynomial so it cuts a closed subset $V(f)$ of $K^n$. Any point $a\notin V(f)$ will give you such an injective function $L_a.$

Comment: If you want to use spoiler text, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396) for how to do that - it can make giving hints like this a little easier. (Be warned that sometimes there can be issues with paragraph breaks in spoiler text - sometimes you have to insert unspoilered text to make something like that work.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are lots of ways to solve this, but one that has a certain elegance to it is to consider the space (say $E$) of linear forms $K^n\to K$, which is of course a vector space of dimension $n$, and to study the map $\Phi: E\to K$ given by
$$L\mapsto \prod_{(x,y)\in V^2} L(x)-L(y).$$

Then $L$ is injective on $V$ if and only if $\Phi(L)=0$. Now try to see (for instance by induction on $|V|$) that $\Phi$ is a non-trivial polynomial map on $E$, so there must be some $L$ such that $\Phi(L)\neq 0$. Note that this only uses that $K$ is infinite, there is no need to assume that it is algebraically closed.